# azure blob use cases for abfss vs https

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I often see a blob has 3 different formats:

- wasb://XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net
- https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/path/to/blob
- abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/paht/to/blob

I know the differences between abfss and wasbs. But I am not quite clear what are the use cases for https vs. abfss. When should we use which format?

Does a blob always have https and abfss formats? In which case we have abfss format but do not have https format?

Comment: here is the answer on this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71780938/6563567