# mount.err while trying to access databricks file system on ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to mount ADLS Gen2 to databricks but I am not able to get list of files after a certain directory using bash/shell script on Databricks.
DBUTILS works fine.

```
import os
os.listdir('/dbfs/mnt/temp')
mount.err

%sh
ls /dbfs/mnt/temp
mount.err

#using dbtuits work
for files in dbutils.fs.ls(external_path):
  print(files.path)

dbfs:/mnt/temp/test1/
```

I tried to unmount and remount but the issue still persists.
I am not able to list anything inside temp but able to see upto
/mnt.
Please let me know, went through other answers but none of them faced this on Gen2.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? And if so: what did the trick?

Comment: I have the same problem on my mounted storage. Any news?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced exactly the same issue. It seems related to the file protocol you use to mount the container. **This error occurs when you use abfss instead of wasbs.**
For reference: [difference between abfss and wasbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277545/what-is-the-difference-between-abfss-and-wasbs-in-azure-storage)

For my tests I've used the storage account access key to have the maxium data authorization possibile and exclude that the problem is connected with data auth. You can use wathever credential you want, just set the correct configs (and the correct protocol).

**0. Unmount**

Be sure to unmount any already mounted container

**1. Define your mount variables**

```
storageAccountName = "<your storage account name>"
storageAccountAccessKey = "<your storage account access key>"
containerName = "<the container you want to mount>"
mountPoint = f"/mnt/{storageAccountName}/{containerName}/"
```

**2. Choose the file protocol**

Using this file protocol `abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/` result in **FAIL** when using python files API to interact with dbfs.

Instead, using this `wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net` will allow python files API to interact **correctly** with dbfs

**3. Execute the mount**

```
if not any(mount.mountPoint == mountPoint for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
    try:
        dbutils.fs.mount(
        source = f"wasbs://{containerName}@{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net".format,
        mount_point = mountPoint,
        extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net': storageAccountAccessKey}
        )
        print("mount succeeded!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("mount exception", e)
```

**4. Test**

Now if you execute

```
import os
os.listdir('/dbfs/mnt/{storageAccountName}/{containerName}')
```

it returns the list of dir/files correctly

**Note**
Anyway I've no clue on why this happens, even considered that in the micrsoft examples for mounting a container they use abfss. [databricks dbfs mounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts)